# Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'TouchPhase'

Tags: touch

Noob here... I am trying to understand why my compiler complains about this:

`if(Input.touchCount >0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase = TouchPhase.Moved)  { ... }`

I am following the tutorial here, at 10:00:
https://youtu.be/ikxcj55BBuE?t=598

Answer (score 0):

Add a `=` to `Input.GetTouch(0).phase = TouchPhase.Moved)`.

This is how your code should look:

```
if(Input.touchCount >0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
```